# Format price in the current locale and currency

Tags: php, magento

I use :

```
$product->getPrice();
```

to get the unformatted price that I can calculate "quantity X price" with ajax.

I want to reformat the total in the current locale and currency. How can I do that?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I think Google could have answered your question ;-) See http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-format-price/.

You can do it with

```
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```

Comment: Google answered mine... it brought me here!

Comment: Careful guys, the currency method not only formats but also converts in the store's currency. If you want formatting but no conversion, then go for Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($price). See method signature for info on the second parameter.

Answer (score 29):

```
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPrice,true,false);
```

Comment: voted up for being the first to provide the answer (the accepted answer only had this info added later)

Comment: ... and the accept answer should've originally been flagged as a link-only-answer for deletion

Answer (score 18):

For formatting the price in another currency than the current one:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('EUR')->toCurrency($price);
```

Answer (score 12):

By this code for formating price in product list

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());
```

Answer (score 4):

Unformatted and formatted:

```
$price = $product->getPrice();
$formatted = Mage::helper('core')->currency($price, true, false);
```

Or use:

```
Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($price, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is a charming answer. Work well on any currency which is selected for store.

```
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```