# Display price php

Tags: php, magento

To display our prices correctly in a slider on Magento I use this line:

```
<?php $first_amount_before_split = number_format($this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()), '2', '.', ',');  $my_array = explode(".", $first_amount_before_split);?>
```

And I echo that line with: `<span class="main-price"><?php echo $my_array[0]; ?>,-</span>`

But prices above 1000 are displayed as: 1,100,- and I want to display this as 1.100,-

So I would like to change the symbol , for a .

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check out number format to accomplish this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Thanks I know that, but I currently use that line already. So how do I need to modify my current code?

Comment: change your last comma to a .

Comment: I tried that, but dat did not work. That prices of 1.000,- are displayed as 1,-

Comment: Then format the number and then do  str_replace() on the , and change it to a .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a localization related thing you are trying to achieve, you should probably use [Magento’s built-in localization methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6730180/1737136) for displaying prices.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not exactly what I want.